Tamagui Sheet - Transform with key translateY must have units

And this is my NewEvent.tsx file
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from 'react'
import { Sheet, Text } from 'tamagui'

interface NewEventProps {
  open: boolean
  onOpenChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

export const NewEvent = ({ open, onOpenChange }: NewEventProps) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(0)

  return (
    <Sheet
      open={open}
      onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
      animation="medium"
      forceRemoveScrollEnabled={open}
      snapPoints={[85, 50, 25]}
      snapPointsMode="percent"
      dismissOnSnapToBottom
      defaultPosition={0}
      position={position}
      zIndex={100_000}
      native={true}
      modal={true}
      onPositionChange={setPosition}>
      <Sheet.Overlay />
      <Sheet.Handle />
      <Sheet.Frame>
        <Text>HELLO</Text>
      </Sheet.Frame>
    </Sheet>
  )
}

And this is my tamagui.config file
import { createFont, createTamagui, createTokens } from 'tamagui'
import { createAnimations } from '@tamagui/animations-css'
import { config as defaultConfig } from '@tamagui/config/v3'

const size = {
  0: 0,

  1: 5,

  2: 10,

  true: 10,
}

export const tokens = createTokens({
  size,

  space: { ...size, '-1': -5, '-2': -10 },

  radius: { 0: 0, 1: 3 },

  zIndex: { 0: 0, 1: 100, 2: 200 },

  color: {
    white: '#FFFFFF',
    surface: '#FAFAF7',
    green: '#6D9773',
    greenDark: '#465E46',
    greenLight: '#DFECDF',
    yellow: '#FFDD82',
    red: '#CC4545',
    grayDark: '#242424',
    gray: '#6E6E6E',
    grayLight: '#EAEAEA',
    black: '#000',
  },
})
const config: any = createTamagui({
  defaultConfig,
  animations: createAnimations({
    fast: {
      damping: 20,
      mass: 1.2,
      stiffness: 250,
    },
    medium: {
      damping: 10,
      mass: 0.9,
      stiffness: 100,
    },
    slow: {
      damping: 20,
      stiffness: 60,
    },
  }),
  fonts: {
    heading: createFont({
      family: 'SoraSemiBold',
      size: {
        1: 12,
      },
    }),
    body: createFont({
      family: 'NotoSans',
      size: {
        1: 12,
      },
    }),
  },

  tokens,

  themes: {
    light: {
      bg: '#f2f2f2',

      color: tokens.color.black,
    },

    dark: {
      bg: '#111',

      color: tokens.color.white,
    },
  },
})
type AppConfig = typeof config

declare module 'tamagui' {
  interface TamaguiCustomConfig extends AppConfig {}
}
export default config

I'm using tamagui version:
    "tamagui": "^1.96.0"

